# Dynamo Db SDK for .NET - what is the preferable way to query data by key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, cloud, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I see that `IDynamoDBContext` from official AWS SDK for DynamoDb has different methods to query stored data:

```
    Task<T> LoadAsync<T>(object hashKey, object rangeKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken));


    AsyncSearch<T> FromQueryAsync<T>(QueryOperationConfig queryConfig, DynamoDBOperationConfig operationConfig = null);
```

`QueryFilter` passed to `QueryOperationConfig` used by *FromQueryAsync()* has a method for adding query conditions with the first parameter named *keyAttributeName*.

```
 public class QueryFilter : Filter
 {

   public void AddCondition(
         string keyAttributeName,
         QueryOperator op,
         params DynamoDBEntry[] values)
...
```

Does this mean that querying DynamoDb with `FromQueryAsync()` set with the correct type of condition (for key attributes) performs as fast as querying data by primary key calling `LoadAsync(hashKey)`?

In other words, are calls to method `A` and method `B` similar in performance?

```
        protected Task<T> A<T>(string hashKey)
        {
            return _dynamoDbContext.LoadAsync<T>(hashKey,
                _consistentReadConfig,
                CancellationToken.None);
        }

        protected async Task<T> B<T>(string hashKey)
        {
            var queryFilter = new QueryFilter();
            queryFilter.AddCondition("HashKeyProperty", QueryOperator.Equal, hashKey); // adding condition for hash key equality

            var queryOperationConfig = new QueryOperationConfig
            {
                Filter = queryFilter
            };

            var queryOperation = _dynamoDbContext.FromQueryAsync<T>(
                queryOperationConfig,
                _consistentReadConfig);

            var results = await queryOperation.GetNextSetAsync();

            return results.SingleOrDefault();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect them to be...though I believe the DDB SLA only applies to GetItem()

But the point of Query() is to return more more than a single record.  Query() is only useful if your table has a composite primary key (hash+sort).  You query() based upon a given (EQ) hash key and possibly some function (LT, GT, Starts with) on the sort key.

GetItem() requires the full primary key, and can only return 1 record.

Point I'm trying to make, your app should know if it has the PK and only needs one record, or if you just have a partial key and expect a list of records back.